# How to read data from TextView in gtk4?

Tags: c, textview, gtk4

I am building a calculator app using c language and gtk4, in `activate` function I have

```
    GtkWidget * entry;
    GObject * Sum = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "sum");
    entry = gtk_entry_new ();
    gtk_entry_set_max_length (GTK_ENTRY (entry), 200);

    g_signal_connect(Sum, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(sum), (gpointer) entry);
```

and the callback function

```
static void sum(GtkWindow * window, gpointer user_data)
{
    const gchar *entry_text;
    //entry_text = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (user_data));
    entry_text = gtk_entry_get_tabs(GTK_ENTRY(user_data));
    g_print("%s\n", entry_text);
}
```

this does not seem to work because when ever i press the sum key I get `(null)` printed to the console

How does one read data from a `TextView` and pass it to a callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GtkEntry`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Entry.html) implements [`GtkEditable`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/iface.Editable.html) interface. So you can do `gtk_editable_get_text (GTK_EDITABLE (entry))` to get the text in a `GtkEntry`.